# Angular 14: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, jit

I'm facing this error, have tried a couple of solutions but none of them works:

> Error: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available.

> The injectable is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
> However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback.

> Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled.
> Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server',
> or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping.

So as I said I have tried a different approaches that I found in the internet:

1. Used babel-loader which seems to be mandatory:

My webpack.js:

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        use: [
          '@ngtools/webpack',
          {
            loader: 'cache-loader',
            options: {
              cacheDirectory: path.resolve('target/cache-loader')
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'thread-loader',
            options: {
              // There should be 1 cpu for the fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin.
              // The value may need to be adjusted (e.g. to 1) in some CI environments,
              // as cpus() may report more cores than what are available to the build.
              workers: require('os').cpus().length - 1
            }
          },
          {
            loader: 'ts-loader',
            options: {
              transpileOnly: true,
              happyPackMode: true
            }
          }
        ],
        exclude: /(node_modules)/
      },
      {
        test: /\.m?js$/,
        exclude: {
          and: [/node_modules/],
          not: [
            /unfetch/,
            /d3-array|d3-scale/,
            /@hapi[\\/]joi-date/,
          ]
        },
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            plugins: ['@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel'],
            compact: false,
            cacheDirectory: true,
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: { implementation: sass }
        }],
        exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
      },
      {
        test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: { implementation: sass }
        }]
      }]
  }
```

In this case maybe putting simple string `'@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel'` into plugins array is the reason but I can't importe it because of that:

> import linkerPlugin from '@angular/compiler-cli/linker/babel';
> ^^^^^^ SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

And when I change `type` to `module` in `package.json` then I have problems with:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const writeFilePlugin = require('write-file-webpack-plugin');
const { merge: webpackMerge } = require('webpack-merge');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
....
```

Which I use in my custom webpack configuration.

2. I tried to run `npm update` - nothing.
3. I put `import '@angular/compiler';` as a first import in the app.main.ts (I know it is not the best solution but even with that it keeps throwing the error)

[image]

A bounch of informations that may be helpful:

```
Package                            Version
@angular/cdk-experimental          14.2.7
@angular/cli                       14.2.10
@angular/flex-layout               14.0.0-beta.41
@angular/material                  14.2.7
@angular/material-moment-adapter   14.2.7
@ngtools/webpack                   14.2.10
@schematics/angular                14.2.10
rxjs                               7.4.0
typescript                         4.6.4
webpack                            5.75.0
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "outDir": "target/classes/static/app",
    "lib": [
      "ES2020",
      "dom"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "app/*": [
        "src/main/webapp/app/*"
      ]
    },
    "importHelpers": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts",
    "src/main/webapp/app/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

I rly stucked in this step and can't find any other solution.. maybe someone of you can help me?

Comment: Did you try by removing 'exclude' section of rule for 'babel-loader'?

Answer (score 1):

In my project, I have a custom webpack configuration file, webpack.config.js, which imports AngularWebpackPlugin from @ngtools/webpack.

I resolved the issue by adding '@angular/compiler' to jitMode.

My **webpack.config.js** is like

```
new AngularWebpackPlugin({
  ...
  jitMode: '@angular/compiler'
})
```

Reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngtools/webpack

Hope it helps!