# How do you load precompiled Angular libraries as dynamic modules?

Tags: angular, plugins

I work on an application that uses an Angular workspace containing several apps and libraries.

The libraries are loaded dynamically as plugins -- the set of plugins for an app is not known at compile-time, so we cannot use any static mechanism.

Before Angular 13, we were able to do the following:

- compile libraries using the default `ng-packagr`
- load the UMD bundle at runtime using SystemJS
- use the Angular compiler's `compiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync` method to compile the Angular module

The code for this plugin loader is [here](https://github.com/OneIdentity/IdentityManager.Imx/blob/v82/imxweb/projects/qbm/src/lib/plugins/plugin-loader.service.ts).

With Angular's removal of direct UMD bundle support, we cannot do this anymore. We have a [workaround in place](https://github.com/OneIdentity/IdentityManager.Imx/blob/v91/imxweb/projects/qbm/src/lib/plugins/plugin-loader.service.ts) that involves running `babel` in the browser, but this is really slow.

We would like to have a build for the plugin libraries that includes bundling, but we have not been able to get this working:

- [Fallback to JIT compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645075/angular-14-the-injectable-platformlocation-needs-to-be-compiled-using-the-jit) is undesirable
- When trying to use [Angular Linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74645075/angular-14-the-injectable-platformlocation-needs-to-be-compiled-using-the-jit) as suggested by [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/42677), the resulting library does not resolve services correctly, despite being called with the same `Injector`. We keep seeing the well-known "No provider for service" errors.

Has anyone been able to get such a setup working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the new [Angular Module Federation](https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-module-federation-in-webpack-5/) [(2)](https://github.com/angular-architects/module-federation-plugin)
With it it's possible to load compiled modules or standalone components dynamically on the fly, from **local** or **remote** source. You will just need to make **an entry point** for the plugin (served manifest) - You can follow a tutorial how to integrate secondary app into host one using dynamic hosts flow except the difference that the secondary app (plugin) itself doesn't need to bootstrap any module/app. So you can leave main.ts empty and delete bootstrap.js. You can also remove zone.js from polyfills as zone will be provided by the host app.

Then in newly created webpack config file inside ModuleFederationPlugin config you expose the modules or **standalone** components you want to consume in host app (this step adds it to the manifest):

```
new ModuleFederationPlugin({
library: { type: 'module' },
name: 'plugin1',
filename: 'pluginEntry.js',
exposes: {
  './pluginModule': './src/app/shared/shared.module.ts',
  './pluginComponent1': './src/app/components/my-component1.ts',
  './pluginComponent2': './src/app/components/my-component2.ts',
},
})
```

Also don't forget to add any exposed modules/standalone components to tsconfig files array.

Start serving the plugin "app".
Then in your main (host) app you load modules or standalone components asynchronously:

```
loadRemoteModule({
          type: 'module',
          remoteEntry: "localhost:4201/pluginEntry.js",
          exposedModule: './pluginModule, // ./pluginComponent1
        }).then(m => 
        createNgModule(m.pluginModule, this.injector)
        // or createComponent(m.pluginComponent1)
        )
```

You attach your components into view, cdk's Portal or load it on a route.

With this solution you can also benefit from shared dependencies across main app and all plugins if any.

Comment: Thanks, but I have reservations about the architecture of the ModuleFederationPlugin. It  inserts itself into the heart of the build process and requires a huge amount of code changes in our case to keep it working.

Comment: @HannoBunjes It is true that for now you need to use the extended Angular builder and custom webpack config and bit of refactoring, though the ModuleFederation is actually part of webpack, not 3rd party. And it's adoption will probably grow even inside Angular core as I read they aspire to introduce micro-services flow in future versions, so you would be on the safer side. FYI I was splitting fairly big project into 3 independent apps and a library and it took me a day. [You can see it in action](https://wemarry.io/en), the mini-site's rows are built-up from externally loaded components.