Angular 17 - dynamically load an Angular library
I have a requirement to load dynamically a library from an URL (that will know at runtime and has the same origin as the SPA) and "display" a component from that library. The library is an angular one.
What I tried is to build the library and imported
private async loadLibrary(url: string): Promise<NgModuleRef<any>> {
    const module = await import(url);
    const moduleFactory = this.compiler.compileModuleSync(module.default);
    // ...

}

The problem that I encountered is that I have the error:

Failed to resolve module specifier "@angular/core". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I see in my library "./fesm2022/mylibrary.mjs" that I have the imports
import * as i0 from '@angular/core';
import { Injectable, Component } from '@angular/core';

Any idea would be greatly appreciated.

Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/a/75527315/16506695

Are you using webpack or babel?

I'm using angular cli, so I guess is babel,
